# JavaScript button click to change variable

Tags: javascript

Hey people I'm doing a complicated statistics project in which I have several numbers displayed and want to change how many decimals they're calculated to. I want to make it so that the viewer of the page can change this number by clicking an increase or decrease button. But right now the only way I know how to change it is through the code itself, which is the "dec" variable at the beginning. Here I have it set to 2 places, but how could I make it so that it changes value with the buttons? Thanks!

```
<input type="button" onclick="increase()" value="Increase"/>
<input type="button" onclick="decrease()" value="Decrease"/>
<br/><table border="1"><tr>
<script type="text/javascript">
dec=2;
for(n=1;n<=9;n++)
{
    document.write("<td>");
    for(t=0;t<=45;t++)
    {
        if(t<n)
        result=0;
        else
        result=fixed(((combin(t,n)*fact(n)*fact(45-n)/fact(45))*100),dec);
        document.write(result);
        zero(result,dec);
        document.write("%<br/>");
    }
    document.write("</td>");
}
function increase()
{
    ???
}
function decrease()
{
    ???
}
function fact(num)
{
    result=1;
    for(cnt=num;cnt>0;cnt--)
    result*=cnt;
    return result;
}
function combin(n,r)
{
    result=fact(n)/(fact(r)*fact(n-r));
    return result;
}
function fixed(num,d)
{
    result=Math.round(num*Math.pow(10,d))/Math.pow(10,d);
    return result;
}
function zero(num,dec)
{
    if(dec!=0&&num-Math.floor(num)==0)
    document.write(".");
    for(cnt=dec;cnt>0;cnt--)
    {
        test=num*Math.pow(10,cnt)
        if(test%10==0)
        document.write("0");
    }
}
</script></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make wrap the for loop in a function with dec as a parameter, then listen for a button click event.

`<button onclick="increase()" text="Increase"></button>`

and the increase function will be something like:

```
function increase(){
  calculate(++dec)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That worked, but actually I just wrote onclick="calc(dec++)" and didn't need a separate function. Thanks!